# How can I apply a piecewise function to every element of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Lets say I have a 2D numpy array, like

```
arr = array([[0, 0.001 , 0.002], [0.03, 0.04, 0.05], [0.01, 0.002, 0.5], [0.05, 0.8, 0.003]])
```

and I want to perform a piecewise function on it, say

```
def gammacor(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x <= 0.00313, x > 0.00313], [12.92*x, 1.055*x**(1/2.4)-0.055])

gcarr = gammacor(arr)
```

When I do this, I get an error:

TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions

If I try to run the function on the flattened array (with the plan to reshape back to n x 3 after running the function), I get the error:

ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 0 output values where the mask is true

Is there an easy way to apply a piecewise function to all elements of a 2D (or ND) array?

Comment: `piecewise` works fine with 2 or 3d arrays.  But your function doesn't even work with a 1d array.

Comment: For some reason, it did work when I called it with a 1d array. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of [np.piecewise](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html#numpy-piecewise) is a funclist.

They should be callables:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 0.001, 0.002], [0.03, 0.04, 0.05], [0.01, 0.002, 0.5],
                [0.05, 0.8, 0.003]])

p = np.piecewise(arr, [arr <= 0.00313, arr > 0.00313],
                 [lambda v: 12.92 * v,
                  lambda v: 1.055 * v ** (1 / 2.4) - 0.055])

print(p)
```

Output:

```
[[0.         0.01292    0.02584   ]
 [0.18974828 0.22091636 0.24780053]
 [0.09985282 0.02584    0.73535698]
 [0.24780053 0.90633175 0.03876   ]]
```

---

```py
def gammacor(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x <= 0.00313, x > 0.00313],
                        [lambda v: 12.92 * v,
                         lambda v: 1.055 * v ** (1 / 2.4) - 0.055])


gcarr = gammacor(arr)
```